# Dummy's not noticed

Tags: duplicate-bridge

In the duplicate bridge game yesterday, I was the declarer and the contract was 3D. My LHO led a H and the RHO won the trick. She led back a H and RHO ruffed with D5. The were 3 hearts in dummy an I said 'small'. My partner, a sweet old lady, played D6 instead of a small H. Nobody noticed this and the LHO led a club which I won. At that point I noticed the mistake, and called the director. What should be the ruling?

Comment: Asked and answered already [here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/34944/what-is-the-penalty-for-the-dummy-failing-to-follow-suit) and discussed in additional detail [here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/32813/in-bridge-is-there-a-penalty-if-dummy-incorrectly-lays-down-his-hand)

Comment: @Forget The linked answers assume or specify rubber bridge, and cite the laws of Contract bridge, not the laws of Duplicate bridge. The answer is essentially the same, but the law numbers and perhaps wording are different.

Comment: @DavidSiegel: Please note that the ACBL Rules Commission for both [Rubber Bridge Laws](https://cdn.acbl.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Laws-of-Rubber-Bridge.pdf) and [Duplicate Bridge](http://web2.acbl.org/documentlibrary/play/laws-of-duplicate-bridge.pdf) are the same individuals, and that the ToC for both clearly shows that all the Laws numbers are the same in both, and the Preface to the Rubber Bridge Laws states: "*The two codes are nearly identical, so far as the nature of their respective games makes it possible.*"

Comment: @Forget, then i think I am out of date, or possibly had different editions. I think the numbering used to be slightly different.

Comment: @DavidSiegel: That is likely correct. I believe the reconciliation of the two code occurred over the past 20 years or so.